# Navbar covered by div, and still covered when z-index is higher

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a navbar that is covered by a div, thus I can't click on the navbar. So I set z-index on the navbar to higher than everything else. However, it still isn't clickable. This is how the elements are set up:

All the divs beside navbar covers navbar, but I set navbar to a higher z-index.

```css
    home {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .background {
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("../../images/mountains.jpg");
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .front {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .header {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .headerContainer {
      width: 55%;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .header h1,
    .header p {
      font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .header h1 {
      font-size: 40px;
    }

    .header p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .arrowDown {
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: 60px;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```
    <div className={classes.background}>
      <Navbar/>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        <div className={classes.headerContainer}>
          <h1>title</h1>
          <p>
            lorem ipsum
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.front}>
        <a href="#aboutBragility" className={classes.arrowDown}>
          <IoIosArrowDown />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is probably a layout issue. Also, this is probably answered somewhere, but I couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet other than just pasting the code? It would be more helpful.

Comment: Looks like not all html is submitted in your post, show the rest of the html.

Comment: what is `home`? I understand you are using react, but please include a [example] with the correct class names so we can fully understand the issue.

Comment: Please see if it has something to do with using `dir` instead of `div`.